# Switch from Bootstrap to Foundation JS errors with Poltergeist

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

Recently we made the switch from Bootstrap to Foundation and naturally a bunch of our feature tests are breaking with Capybara (with a Poltergeist driver). When I run my "suite" (only using one test example here), I get the following error:

```
 1) AccountManagement adding a new account and skipping payments integration
     Failure/Error: sign_in_with www_sign_in_url, account.owner.email, 'valid_password'
     Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
       One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

       SyntaxError: Parse error
       SyntaxError: Parse error
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/poltergeist-1.5.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:275:in `command'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/poltergeist-1.5.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:29:in `visit'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/poltergeist-1.5.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:89:in `visit'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:227:in `visit'
     # /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/support/features/session_helpers.rb:12:in `sign_in_with'
     # ./spec/features/account_management_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:115:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:112:in `times'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Unfortunately, when I checkout the "www_sign_in_url" I don't see any JS errors in the chrome console.

This is what the suite looks like:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "AccountManagement", :type => :feature do

  let!(:port_number)         { 3001 }
  let!(:account)             { create(:account, owner: create(:owner, password: 'valid_password', confirmed_at: Time.now, tour: true)) }
  let!(:sign_in_url)         { "http://#{account.subdomain}.lvh.me:#{port_number}/admin/sign_in" }
  let!(:www_sign_in_url)     { "http://www.lvh.me:#{port_number}/admin/sign_in" }
  let!(:store_url)           { "http://#{account.subdomain}.lvh.me:#{port_number}/" }
  let!(:sign_up_with_stripe) { "http://#{account.subdomain}.lvh.me:#{port_number}/admin/payment_integration" }

  before(:each) do
    Capybara.server_port = port_number
    Capybara.app_host = root_url
    Capybara.default_wait_time = 15
  end

  scenario 'adding a new account and skipping payments integration', :js => true do
    sign_in_with www_sign_in_url, account.owner.email, 'valid_password'
    expect(page).to have_content('Manage stores')

    click_on 'Add store'
    expect(page).to have_content('Basic Store Info')

    fill_in "account[business_attributes][name]", with: 'newstore'
    fill_in "account[subdomain]", with: 'newstore'

    click_on 'Skip payment setup'

    expect(page).to have_content('Welcome')
  end
```

This is what the sign_in_with method looks like:

```
def sign_in_with(sign_in_url, email, password, user_type = 'user')
  visit sign_in_url
  fill_in "#{user_type}[email]", with: email
  fill_in "#{user_type}[password]", with: password
  click_button 'SIGN IN'
end
```

Where else can I check for a JS error if not the chrome console?

Comment: go back to bootstrap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found that the path to one of my javascript files was incorrect. Thus, a parse error was determined.

To find this error, I used remote debugging with Poltergeist and was able to see this error more clearly.

To do this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_debug do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :inspector => true)
end

# Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist_debug
```

And then within your test, you can add `page.driver.debug` which pauses the script and loads another browser.